# old xorg in 16.04

Tags: xorg, 16.04

I am using 14.04 LTS on a old macbook pro 15" (2,2, Year 2007) with the utopic release of xorg because using newer releases (like wily) breaks suspend/resume. If I will upgrade to 16.04, will I be able to keep xorg utopic?

Comment: I think you should be able to mark the package to be held back with apt-get, but I am not sure if that will or will not break things

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade the system to 16.04, a new version of Xorg will be installed.

It is not possible to use old version of Xorg, because it will break dependencies.

You can keep using Ubuntu 14.04 if you have problems with the new releases.

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply. In Ubuntu 14.04, which I am actually using, there are several versions of xorg to use, such as utopic, vivid, wily etc.(utopic is the one working for me). I hoped that it was the same for the new LTS 16.04...

Comment: With 16.04, there will be several versions of xorg as newer releases are made (from 16.10, 17.04, etc.). Older versions aren't ported (you won't find, for example, saucy's xorg on 14.04)